# Visual Studio 2016 C++ - MFC Dll has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, breakpoints

I tried to find a solution all the day, but nothing. Now I need your help...
I have an MFC DLL (in which one I would like to put a GUI), but this DLL is totally empty actually, just an class declaration I export. I also have an MFC application to test my DLL, also pretty empty.
When I access the DLL I have an exception: MFCApplication1.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

[MFCApplication1.exe has triggered a breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY7YA.png)

I share to you the 2 projects (the application and the DLL) to have all my settings [=> Here](https://www.zipshare.com/download/eyJhcmNoaXZlSWQiOiI3NDBhODQxZS05OTZkLTQ3MjAtYmViYi1hNGVhZWMxMGI0YzIiLCJlbWFpbCI6Inlvb2VwbGFAZ21haWwuY29tIn0=).

Thank you in advance for your help ! :)

For everyone who just want to see the code :

DLL Header :

> ```
> // CANExamplesValidation.h : main header file for the CANExamplesValidation DLL
> //
> #pragma once
>
> #ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
> #error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
> #endif
>
> #include "resource.h"       // main symbols
>
> #ifdef CANExamplesValidation_EXPORTS
> #define CCppPracticeLibraryApp_API __declspec(dllexport) 
> #else
> #define CCppPracticeLibraryApp_API __declspec(dllimport) 
> #endif
>
>
> // CCANExamplesValidationApp
> // See CANExamplesValidation.cpp for the implementation of this class
> //
>
> class CCppPracticeLibraryApp_API CCANExamplesValidationApp : public CWinApp
> {
> public:
> /*    CCANExamplesValidationApp();
>   void SayHelloWorld();
> // Overrides
> public:
>   virtual BOOL InitInstance();
>
>   DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()*/
> };
> ```

DLL Body :

> ```
> // CANExamplesValidation.cpp : Defines the initialization routines for the DLL.
> //
>
> #include "stdafx.h"
> #include <Windows.h>
> #include "CANExamplesValidation.h"
>
> /*#ifdef _DEBUG
> #define new DEBUG_NEW
> #endif
> */
>
> // CCANExamplesValidationApp
> /*
> BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCANExamplesValidationApp, CWinApp)
> END_MESSAGE_MAP()
>
>
> // CCANExamplesValidationApp construction
>
> CCANExamplesValidationApp::CCANExamplesValidationApp()
> {
>   AfxMessageBox(L"CCANExamplesValidationApp");
>   // TODO: add construction code here,
>   // Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
>   //MessageBox(NULL, _T("Help, Something went wrong."), _T("Error"), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
> }
>
>
> // The one and only CCANExamplesValidationApp object
>
> //CCANExamplesValidationApp theApp;
>
>
> // CCANExamplesValidationApp initialization
>
> BOOL CCANExamplesValidationApp::InitInstance()
> {
>   AfxMessageBox(L"InitInstance before");
>   CWinApp::InitInstance();
>   AfxMessageBox(L"InitInstance after");
>
>   return TRUE;
> }
>
>
> void CCANExamplesValidationApp::SayHelloWorld()
> {
>   AfxMessageBox(L"hello world");
>   //AfxMessageBox(L"hello world");
>   //MessageBox(NULL, _T("Help, Something went wrong."), _T("Error"), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
>   //printf("Hello world");
> }*/
> ```

Declaration of the class in the main of MFC project :

> CCANExamplesValidationApp testCallingLibrary; // Before it was a
>   pointer

Comment: What happens if you hit the "Break" button [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY7YA.png)?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your attention.
When I hit break button I enter to debuging mode, I post you to screenshot  :
![1 - Output line with code](http://imageshack.com/a/img923/6492/NbfVUv.png)
![2 - Call stack](http://imageshack.com/a/img921/4636/pSzYaB.png)

Thanks